# List intersection and partial string matching in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, string-matching

So i have 2 lists the first comes from my dataset and contains dates-times in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm', named `times`. Example:

```
'2010-01-01 00:00', '2010-01-01 00:15', '2010-01-01 00:30', ...,
```

The other is a list of all the unique year month combinations, named `year_and_month`. Example:

```
'2010-01', '2010-02', '2010-03', '2010-04',
```

So i try to extract all the indices of a year-month combination in the original dataset. I do that using the worst ways (new in python), namely

```
each_member_indices = []
for i in range(len(year_and_month)):
    item_ind = []
    for j in range(times.shape[0]):
        if year_and_month[i] in times[j]:
            item_ind.append(j)

each_member_indices.append(item_ind)
```

Now, this is a nuke for taking so much time to work. So i wanted to optimise it a bit and thus i was looking at some implementations such as
[Find intersection of two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/find-intersection-of-two-lists/642919#642919) and [Python: Intersection of full string from list with partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389010/python-intersection-of-full-string-from-list-with-partial-string) the problem being that

```
res_1 = [val for val in year_and_month if val in times]
```

yields an empty list, whereas

```
res_1 = [val for val in year_and_month if val in times[0]]
```

yields the first member at least.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

I am only in need of the indices of the elements from the original dataset named `times` corresponding the unique year-month pairs of the `year_and_month` list. So as requested a sample output would be

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3,...],[925, 926, ...],...]
```

The first sublist contains the indices for the pair 2010-January, the second for the 2010-February and so on.

Comment: Can you show a sample desired output for your input?

Comment: You are right! As i was looking at the solutions i discovered that i get what i want through the for loop but the list comprehension is not serving the same purpose. To answer your question i m a getting a list of lists namely `each_member_indices` is `[[0,1,2,..], [924, 925,...],...]` each sublist corresponding to the unique year month pair, so for example the first sublist is all the indices for the January 2010 period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that in linear time, you could build a lookup dictionary mapping year and month combinations to indices. You can also use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make it a bit easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, v in enumerate(times):
    d[v[:7]].append(i)
```

Then you can create the result list with a list comprehension:

```
result = [d[x] for x in year_and_month]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> times = ['2010-01-01 00:00', '2010-01-01 00:15', '2010-02-01 00:30', '2010-03-01 00:00']
>>> year_and_month = ['2010-01', '2010-02', '2010-03', '2010-04']
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, v in enumerate(times):
...     d[v[:7]].append(i)
...     
>>> dict(d)
{'2010-01': [0, 1], '2010-02': [2], '2010-03': [3]}
>>> [d[x] for x in year_and_month]
[[0, 1], [2], [3], []]
```

Comment: So if i want to extract '2010-01'  i should be able to by writing `d['2010-01']`. However when i do `result = [d[x] for x in year_and_month]` this gives me a list where `len(result) == len(times)`. However i would prefer a list `result` having length the same as the unique year-month combinations, i.e the same as the result in your demo. Is this maybe a problem coming from the fact that i m using python 3?

Comment: Perhaps, each element in `times` has unique year-month then? A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) creates a new list of the same size as the input one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using an any?

```
[val for val in year_and_month if any(val in t for t in times)]
```

Comment: **Note** that I didn't try your original code, and not sure what output you are looking for

Comment: Quite some caveats ;) Maybe a comment clarifying the question would be better

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a new structure with a dictionary and order them by year_and_month?

```
result = {}
for i, v in enumerate(times):
    result.setdefault(v[:7], []).append(i)
for i in year_and_month:
     print(i, result[i]) #will print the year_month with all the indices of that year_month
```

Answer (score 0):

alright, this gives the common elements:

```
ls = str(times)
r = [x for x in year_and_month if (x in ls)]
print r
```